# Selenium Chromedriver throwing element click intercepted when there's a placeholder for an input box

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have an input box of whose HTML structure looks like the following.

[image]

I'm using the following XPath to click on the element through Selenium.

```
//input[@class='Select-input']
```

Though this XPath only matches the input element and not the placeholder, when trying to click, Selenium chrome driver throws the following exception.

```
 Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: element click intercepted: Element <input aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" class="Select-input" role="combobox" value=""> is not clickable at point (519, 348). Other element would receive the click: <div class="Select-placeholder">...</div>
```

(Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

I tried waiting for the element to be clickable and also tried the following.

```
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", searchField);
```

Neither of them helped. Any help/advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly the the HTML markup wasn't of the desired element.

Comment: Don't see the <input> element in the above markup you posted. Can you please post the markup with <input> element in it. Another ask - What are you trying to achieve by clicking on the input element?

Comment: @SitamJana Edited the question with the input element also in place. I'm trying to input text in this box and click a button. But since the sendKeys on this method was throwing error, I tried clicking it, and that's when I saw the above mentioned error

Comment: @DebanjanB When I use the xpath and search in chrome console, there's only 1 element identified and that's the one I expected to as well

Comment: Instead of locating the element through xpath, locate the element through the inspector and construct the xpath

Comment: Yes that's how the xpath was written. I did the opposite just to confirm that it works